# SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

When I  make event with "guildMemberAdd" I`m get err: **SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment**. Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')

bot.on('GUILD_MEMBER_ADD' = async (bot, message, guild) => {
    let nameserv = guild.name
    let emb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Приветствие.')
        .setDescription(`Добро пожаловать на сервер **${nameserv}**!`)
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('EVENT SYSTEM')
    guild.member.send(emb)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be attempting to set "bot.on('GUILD_MEMBER_ADD'" to the async function. Both 'GUILD_MEMBER_ADD' and the async function are arguments to the bot.on function and should be separated by a , not an =.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')

bot.on('GUILD_MEMBER_ADD', async (bot, message, guild) => {
    let nameserv = guild.name
    let emb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Приветствие.')
        .setDescription(`Добро пожаловать на сервер **${nameserv}**!`)
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('EVENT SYSTEM')
    guild.member.send(emb)
})
```

Comment: You're right. Also, GUILD_MEMBER_ADD is not a valid event for discord.js, it's guildMemberAdd.